# Are wooden shafts competitive to carbon ones?

Tags: gear, archery, arrows

I know a lot of archers who emotionally prefer wooden shafts:

- More "traditional"
- Environmental-friendly if lost
- Just general personal preferences

However, do they (the arrows) have any rational characteristics which can make them superior over carbon ones?

Edit: Besides that they are generally cheaper :)

Comment: is being environmental-friendly (not only if lost, but to manufacture too) not a rational reason?

Comment: @njzk2 I would say it's relative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certain styles of archery, like some traditional longbow styles, will actually prescribe that you must use wooden arrows. Example: [British Clout Archery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clout_archery#BLBS_clout)

Apart from this and the couple of side effects you mentioned (cheaper, more traditional, ...) I don't think there are any benefits in using wooden shafts.

I dare say that you could find any wished for ballistic or other relevant attributes in carbon and/or aluminium arrows. Or at the very least you could manufacture such shafts.